# Utf 8 issue when saving an entity

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, character-encoding

I use spring boot 2 with jpa, hibernate and postgres.

In my build.gradle, I have

> tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
>       options.compilerArgs = ["-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation", "-parameters"]
>       options.encoding = "UTF-8"
>     }

I posted some class here https://pastebin.com/WgDqZkjf

I get problem with utf8

In debug I see

```
    select
        nextval ('ignar.hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('ignar.samples_id_seq')
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        ignar.samplings
        (available_for_test, build_date, color_id, dimension_id, machine_id, print, product_id, reception_date, remark, special_try, test_done, to_print, delay_before_doing_test, press, quantity_received, dtype, id, year) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'TraditionalSamplings', ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        ignar.samples
        (created_at, updated_at, absorption_printed, aen_remarque, certificat_include, cube, durability_printed, fresh_density, fresh_weigth, gen_remarque, label, position, sample_letter, sampling_id, sampling_year, absorption, absorption_number, coloration, coloration_number, compression, compression_number, density, draw_down, draw_down_number, durability, durability_number, granulometry, granulometry_number, organic_material, organic_material_number, scaling, scaling_number, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-05-21 15:38:21.214  WARN 2973 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22021
2018-05-21 15:38:21.215 ERROR 2973 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00
2018-05-21 15:38:21.215 ERROR 2973 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement]
```

Comment: Why do you think it a UTF-8 issue?

Comment: like t's wrote:  ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Comment: That means you are trying to feed non-UTF-8 data from your database through something that expects the bytes to decode to UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably your char is causing the issue... try to convert it to String in your java file

Comment: don't know if i could use char... but with a string.. that working